# Connector in flowchart application using Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

My requirement is to create Flowchart kind of application in Silverlight. Dragging the elements from toolbar to canvas, I have done. Now Im looking to create a Connector, which will connect the elements on canvas dynamically..

It would be helpful, if anyone have idea to how to go about it...

Answer (score 0):

You could consider a behavior.  Here is a sample connect behavior:

http://www.dataartist.net/blog/post/Silverlight-Behavior-Modifications-2-ConnectBehavior.aspx